# BigQuery table contains mystery duplicate rows

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table that claims to contain 87 rows, but when queried returns 5916 rows.  There are 68 identical (according to count(*)/group by) copies of each of the rows I expected to see.

This table was created using the Java SDK by querying `publicdata:samples.wikipedia` with a `WHERE id=1711042` into a destination table with a `Write Preference` of `Overwrite Table`.  The target table did already exist with the same 87 rows.  I can rerun this query+table overwrite multiple times with no change to the number of mystery rows.

Running `SELECT * FROM [publicdata:samples.wikipedia] WHERE id=1711042` on its own returns 87 rows.

Creating a new table with the same query results in the correct number of rows being queryable.  I expect that if I drop the offending table and recreate it from scratch it will be fixed.

I think I've made the table in question `safe.com:fme-big-query-api:testsuite.pr46492_nonpublic_read` visible to the world if anyone wants to confirm my claims.

Is it corrupt?  Is it my fault?  Is there any way I can avoid corrupting tables in the future?  All suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for this report; you've hit a regression where we're in certain cases truncated data shows up in query results. (this only happens if you have a table that was written out as the result of a query). The problem is only in the interpretation of the tables, the tables themselves are not corrupt.

This has been fixed and the fix is now live. I've retried the query and a `SELECT COUNT(*) ...` now returns the correct number of rows.

Comment: Yes indeed, I'm getting 87 rows again.  Thanks for the fast turnaround!

Comment: Did you deshare my dataset as well?  Not a problem if you did, but confusing when I went back to lock it down.

Comment: Nope .. I didn't touch the dataset, other than to run the query against it to investigate the bug.